# Can not Connect Drupal to DB only on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, drupal, drupal-6

uploaded an existing drupal codebase to a virtual host set up on AWS. it is showing "can not connect to database"

I created database "dbname" and can connect fine through ssh. But can not get settings.php to connect. As far as I can tell the mysql user has all needed permissions to access the db remotely.

what I have

```
$db_url = 'mysql://username:password@us-west-rds.amazonaws.com/dbname';
```

Here is example of settings.php with a drupal 7 site of ours that connects fine

```
$databases = array (
  'default' => 
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'database' => 'dbname',
      'username' => 'dbuser',
      'password' => 'password',
      'host' => 'us-west-rds.amazonaws.com',
      'port' => '3306',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue with ec2 - rds connection in my drupal 7 installation. Can you tell me how did you solved this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several things to check:

- do you have the security group open to allow access from your server (as said by Bob Kinney in the other answer)?
- do you have a firewall set up on your server that prevents connecting to your RDS instance?
- does your user have sufficient rights to connect to your database?

The easiest way to debug this is to use the console `mysql` command and try to connect to your instance from there:

```
mysql dbname -u username -p password -h db01b2.ck1dmcn6kfws.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com
```

If this does not work, check the points given above. If this works and does not work in Drupal only, check your PHP code and/or Drupal config.

Comment: drupal config? you mean settings.php this is not an issue with the code as it connects fine on another server

Comment: Actually I seem to be having a similar issue. On the same server using the root user of the mysql instance (so it's not a firewall or permissions issue), I can easily update my Drupal 7 installation to run from RDS but not my Drupal 6.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you may not have set up your security groups to allow access from your EC2 instances.  You'll want to make sure your DB security group has an ingress rule to allow traffic from your EC2 instance/security group.

[How do I control network access to my DB Instance(s)?](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/#31)

Comment: if this was the case why is the drupal install on a different virtual host connecting

Comment: @alex_b depending on how you've configured your security groups, it is possible that the vhost that can connect is running in a security group from the one than can.  I suggest you also take a look at j0nes answe as well as he offers some additional possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

You're pointing at the wrong hostname.

```
'host' => 'us-west-rds.amazonaws.com'
```

Each individual database instance will have it's own hostname. You can look it up in the AWS Console. The one you're currently pointing to looks like you intended to point to the RDS web service API endpoint.

Answer (score -1):

You might also want to check...

`setsebool httpd_can_network_connect_db on`